# Concurrent queue is not dequeued/cleared

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

My requirement is to insert item in a queue and process it but the **items should be added first** and after a while they should be processed (as some other things needs to be set before processing the items. Here is the coding I have done so far.

```
    #region Variables Declarations

    private Thread threadTask = null;

    ConcurrentQueue<string> concurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();     
    string currentSeqNo;
    string previousSeqNo = "-1";        

    #endregion

    private void test1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddItems();           

        if (threadTask == null)
        {
            threadTask = new Thread(Kick);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);               
            threadTask.Start();
        }
    }

    private void AddItems()
    {
        for (Int64 i = 100000; i < 300000; i++)
        {                
            concurrentQueue.Enqueue(i.ToString());
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {                    
                label1.Text = i.ToString();
                label1.Update();                   
            }));
        }
    }

    private void Kick()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int recordCountNew = concurrentQueue.Count();
            if (recordCountNew != 0)
            {
                RemoveItems();
            }
        }
    }

    private void RemoveItems()
    {
        string item;

        while (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out item))
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {                   
                label2.Text = item;
                label2.Update();
            }));

            currentSeqNo = item;    // second time does not start wil 100000

            if (previousSeqNo != "-1")
            {
                if (long.Parse(currentSeqNo) != long.Parse(previousSeqNo) + 1)
                {
                    Reconnect();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Process item
                    previousSeqNo = currentSeqNo;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Process item
                previousSeqNo = currentSeqNo;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Reconnect()
    {            
        currentSeqNo = "";
        previousSeqNo = "-1";

        string someItem;
        while (concurrentQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out someItem);
        }

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            label1.Text = "";
            label2.Text = "";

            label1.Update();
            label2.Update();
        }));

        AddItems();

        if (threadTask == null)
        {
            threadTask = new Thread(Kick);                
            threadTask.Start();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reconnect();
    }
```

To reproduce the issue: Run the app and in the middle click on the button. Now the queue should again be started from 100000 but it shows the number somewhere greater than 100000.

Please advise how do I release all the resources to make a fresh start after  clicking a button. Though I am setting them to default and also clearing the queue but  it still shows the old values in currentSeqNo when 'RemoveItems' method is called.

Comment: If your remove items works faster than your add items your queue ends early, you should look in to using a `BlockingCollection<string>` instead, it uses `ConcurrentQueue` as it's default backing collection.

Comment: I tried BlockingCollection but the situation remains the same.

Comment: why not create a new ConcurrentQueue instead  and swap the reference ?

Comment: ConcurrentQueue<string> wssMessagesQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
             concurrentQueue = wssMessagesQueue;

Comment: tried this.. but still not much luck

Comment: I think I need to stop the thread or release its resource so that new thread can start afresh.. but stopping a thread would be not good

Answer (score 0):

Couple of comments:

1) You `Kick()` method have an infinite loop, that too without sleep. Every thread started will keep on running as you didn't have a scope for thread to come out.

You can have a member variable like `bKeepRunning` with default value as `true`. Set that variable to `false` in beginning of `Reconnect()` function. Something like:

```
private void Kick()
{
    while (bKeepRunning)
    {
        int recordCountNew = concurrentQueue.Count();
        if (recordCountNew != 0)
        {
            RemoveItems();
        }
    }
}
```

2. Why do you have `Thread.Sleep(5000);` in `test1_Load()`? I dont think that is needed.

I made small change in your code, something like:

```
private void AddItems()
{
    for (Int64 i = 100000; i < 300000; i++)
    {
        concurrentQueue.Enqueue(i.ToString());

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
            label1.Update();
        }));

        if (i < 100004)
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private void Kick()
{
    while (bKeepRunning)
    {
        int recordCountNew = concurrentQueue.Count();
        if (recordCountNew != 0)
        {
            RemoveItems();
        }
    }
} 

private void Reconnect()
{
    currentSeqNo = "";
    previousSeqNo = "-1";
    bKeepRunning = false;
    threadTask = null;

    string someItem;
    while (concurrentQueue.Count > 0)
    {
    concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out someItem);
    }

    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
    {
    label1.Text = "";
    label2.Text = "";

    label1.Update();
    label2.Update();
    }));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    AddItems();

    bKeepRunning = true;


    if (threadTask == null)
    {
    threadTask = new Thread(Kick);
    threadTask.Start();
    }
}
```

It helped me to see that value is starting from 100000. You can try the same at your end.

Note: I have stopped  thread and restarted after clicking on button. Hence i dont see any flaw in your code as such. It just runs fast so that you are not able to realize start values.

Comment: Use the above code which will demonstrate stopping/restarting thread as well. The 1 second delay before first 4 values will allow you to notice it restarts from 100000.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a race condition between the Kick thread and the button click handler. When you press the button you execute Reconnect() in it you clean the queue and then call the AddItems() function. But all this time the Kick function tries to Dequeue and so you end up each time with an arbitrary amount of items in it. What you should do is to synchronize between these functions or prevent the Kick from executing while you are adding items.

Comment: Thanks jason for understanding. I am stuck so badly that I don't know how to stop a thread and restart it again. I don't know how to do synchronization. Trying so many things but nothing fits with my requirement which is to run two threads in parallel wherein one is enqueuing and another dequeuing. It is compulsory to start receiving messages first and then after a while process them. It works first time perfectly but the moment I need to do the same steps again it does not work properly as the threads are not stopped and I am getting arbitrary  values. Can you advise how to make them in sync?

Comment: Just change to BlockingCollection<string> as @Scott Chamberlain  suggested. Use the TryAdd/TryTake. Also when you check make sure you are checking the state after the AddItems() call.

Comment: I tried with blockingcollection but the results are same. AddItems() call will always add the values in the collection.So where do I check the state - in Reconnect() method? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should make *UI thread* and *threadTask thread* sync, just use **ManualResetEventSlim** Signal Construct to, like this:

```
static ManualResetEventSlim guard = new ManualResetEventSlim(true);
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    guard.Reset();
    Reconnect();
    guard.Set();
}
private void RemoveItems()
{
    string item;

    while (concurrentQueue.TryDequeue(out item))
    {
        guard.Wait();
        //......
     }
}
```

see:

> [ManualResetEventSlim Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualreseteventslim(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Does not work.. still it gives the random number and does not start with 100000

Comment: Maybe you can set a breakpoint at AddItems Method to see the exact number.

Comment: AddItems always start with 100000 but when dequeuing it takes random number because that is a separate thread and it does not clear the resources

Comment: Also AddItems is just a test app in production the numbers would keep coming infinitely

Comment: @user1254053, when you call guard.Reset(), threadTask Thread will be blocked until you call guard.Set(). So all resources in queue will be  cleared.

Comment: Thanks Ice Younger.I have coded the way you have suggested but it still shows me the random number when I click the button in middle of the processing. When I put a break pointy on  previousSeqNo = currentSeqNo; the currentSqbNo should show 100000 but it shows arbitary value.